# Enter colors directly into notebook?

Tags: notebooks, color

In Mathematica notebook interface, you can evaluate:

```
In[1]:= Black
```

and you get a colored squared representing the color. Then I can copy and paste this color square and use it as input, like so:

[image]

which I find very readable. However I would like to be able to enter the blue square directly, instead of having to enter and evaluate `Blue` in a separate cell to get to the square.

Is there a key combination (similar to the usual `Esc + a + Esc` to get greek letters) to get the color boxes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the colour swatch to appear as follows:

1. Type the symbol `Black`.
2. Press and hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys.
3. Type <kbd>←</kbd> to select the previous word.
4. Type <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it in place.
5. Release the modifier keys.

[image: screen recording]

Answer (score 8):

```
SystemDialogInput["Color"] // CopyToClipboard
```

Will do the Trick together with Copy/Past

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As Kuba noted in a comment you can use the menu command *Evaluation >> Evaluate in Place*

[image: picture]